# aspx slideshow with images from database

Tags: jquery, asp.net, image, slideshow

I want to create a slideshow in jquery.

but my files are located in a database.

Can I create a jquery-slideshow from a List of Images

Comment: your files are located in database of just path or url of the files are stored ??

Comment: do have files in the database or the file path?

Comment: I have the images stored and not the path

Answer (score 0):

I think you have only paths in your db ,and images would be in a folder only ,with the help of datalist or repeater you can easily create the jquery slider ,you just need to put datalist or repeater in the place of the images in the examples.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/sapnabeniwal/a-glimpse-to-image-slideshow-using-jquery/

Slide the images in ASP.NET using jQuery. We often see this inside websites that at the corner, images slide one by one; it may be advertisement images or the images you want to display for commercially or for look and feel. By using this type of functionality we can give an awesome effect to our website that will produce a great effect on the user of the website. You often seen that these are basically built on flash but by using jQuery in ASP.NET we can build this type of functionality.